# Coordinating the padding of structs in C++ and Objective-C

Tags: c++, objective-c, struct, padding, metal

I’m using Objective-C and Metal to render to a window, however all of my application code is written in C++. So all of the CPU manipulation of data inside `MTLBuffer` is done in C++. This is done by passing the buffers contents (which is a `void*`) to the C++ code, where it casts the contents pointer to `MyVertex*` to write new vertex data. In my header file, i just add compiler conditions to type the vertex structs properly.

```
#ifdef __IN_OBJC__
#define V2 vector_float2
#define V4 vector_float4
#endif

#ifdef __IN_CPP__
#define V2 vec2
#define V4 vec4
#endif

typedef struct {
    V2 position;
    V4 color;
} MyVertex;
```

Here `vec2`, `vec4` are basically structs of 2, 4 floats implemented in my C++ code. But in this example, Objective-C and C++ think that `MyVertex` is of differing sizes. I’m compiling with clang and clang++. And the Objective-C compiler wants to pad the struct so it is of size 32, while C++ says that the struct is of size 24. I currently fixed this now with `#pragma pack`, but this feels like a weak solution. I would actually prefer my C++ implementation to be padded instead of packed to better optimize buffers in the shaders. But I cannot deliberately pad a struct like I can pack one.

Should I make my own vectors (`vec2`…) compatible with Objective-C? Right now they are written as classes. That way i won’t have to do conditional declarations. I would prefer the solution to best optimize buffer performance in the shader.

Comment: Is the real problem that every element of a `MyVertex[]` will start at multiples of 24 in C++ and multiples of 32 in Objective-C? If so, you can use `alignas(32)` modifier to make sure you match Objective-C.

Comment: @Botje No The Objective-C compiler pads the internals of each `MyVertex` struct, so that `position` is size 8, then pad 8, and then `color` is 16. I mean I could manually hack it so I the structs align, but that doesn't feel like best practice.

Comment: If I use`alignas(32)` with `MyVertex` in C++, then C++ will think `color` has an offset of 4 still, and Objective-C will think that `color` has an offset of 8.

Comment: You can also use `alignas(16)` on individual field members. This is reminiscent of the OpenGL struct layout problem...

Comment: So I align within the struct. And Both Objective-C and C++ will compile the same format if it is specified that way. That seems like a good solution

Comment: In fact I'm sure I can go deeper with `alignas` and optimize a lot more to focus on shader buffer and cache hits.. Somehow. Will have to read a bit more how that works.

Comment: You may want to read up on a similar (inspirational?) issue in OpenGL land: [std140 vs std430 layout](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Interface_Block_(GLSL))

Comment: clang and clang++ will use the same layout. Your problem is that your vector_float2 does not require the right alignment, at least it's not the same as vec2.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since Objective-C expects every field of your struct to align at a 16-byte (4 floats) boundary, you can ask C++ to do the same with `alignas(16)`

```
struct MyVertex {
    alignas(16) V2 position;
    alignas(16) V4 color;
};
```

This will adjust the offsets and resulting size of `MyVertex`:

```
offsetof(MyVertex, position):0
offsetof(MyVertex, color):16
sizeof(MyVertex): 32
```

Comment: This is not even the right answer. The real answer is to make sure that alignment on different vectors structs that you defined is the same across the places that it gets included.

Comment: I was under the impression that the alignment of struct members was similar to std140 in OpenGL, where *every* member must be aligned to the largest alignment in the struct, frequently that of vec4. This means a single int gets padded up to 32 bytes. How would you achieve this without explicit alignment hints for c++?

Comment: What's the alignment of `vector_float2` and `vec2`?

Comment: [*The float2 type in the Metal structure requires an alignment of 8 bytes.*](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/6258/11366) See also p26 of the [Metal spec](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf)

Comment: I know what it requires. I'm asking you what's in your code, because you have these funny defines.

Comment: its my code not @Botje ‘s code.  vec2 is defined as a class template in C++. Templated for type and length. So a vector of 2 floats or 4 ints etc. will be the same code. so it’s super not portable to Objective-C. the only attribute to an instance is an `std::array`. (i used this for convenient constructors with `initializer_list` but i’m not married to `std::array`.

Comment: But the std::array I don't think is a problem, because it will pack the floats together, WITHIN a single vector which is what `vector_floatx` also does.

Answer (score -1):

If all manipulations is done in C++ then you don't need to know anything about `MyVertex` content in ObjectiveC. In ObjectiveC you can work just with pointer on it.

Yours declaration file should be:

```
#ifdef __IN_CPP__
struct MyVertex {
    vec2 position;
    vec4 color;
};
#else
typedef struct _MyVertex MyVertex;
#endif
```

Comment: This makes no sense as well as the other answer. What's `_MyVertex` even? How can you work with "just pointer" to something if you don't know it's layout? What

Comment: @Spo1ler You also provider all necessary functions to work with it that accepts that pointer. For example many functions in corefoundation using that approach.

Comment: @Spo1ler `_MyVertex` is struct forward declaration and code sugar to not write `struct MyVertex`